# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask about industrial textile machinery?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Currently I'm looking for an industrial machine that can do something very specific concerning textile printing, and I don't even know if it exists.

After googling around without success I wanted to get help from someone else on a Stack Exchange site but I found nowhere to post my question.

So is there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions about chain manufacturing or industrial processes regarding textile printing?

Comment: What type of thing/industry? We have a site for home improvement, another for motor vehicle maintenance & repair, and another for electrical engineering, so the _type_ of 'something' is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

We don't appear to have a site covering that. We have a [Crafts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60509/crafts) proposal, but that might not actually be open to questions for a while yet.

Have you considered telephoning companies offering textile printing services in your area to inquire about their services instead? Alternately, if you're looking to *purchase* industrial equipment, presumably you should be speaking to suppliers to find something that suits your needs.

Without understanding your motives it's unclear how to advise you on proceeding, though. If you just want to know about the machinery, not actually make any use of it, it may be worth speaking to one of these people anyway.